# SP 2013 Usage Reports

Tags: reports, site-usage, usage-counters

Is there any way to change the date ranges found in the Usage Reports?  I can't seem to locate anything that will change the range in the "daily" section.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the converted excel to filter date.

[image]

or you could use the Audit Logs Report and click Custom Report, where you can set date range.

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: I can't seem to locate the Audit Logs Report.  Is that something only a SCA (not simply a SA) can access?